# How to build facebook's scribe?

Tags: c++, facebook, boost, scribe-server

I just downloaded the source code of facebook's scribe. I'm new to it and having read the readme.build file , I can say I could barely understand how to build it. Could anyone give me the step by step procedures? thanks... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is follow the readme/build instructions that came with the package. If you don't have Linux installed in your PC, you can simply use a VM and install linux in it...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a detailed tutorial on how to build Scribe from the source on Linux (Fedora) here:

http://www.alphadevx.com/a/84-Installing-Facebook-Scribe-on-Fedora-8

It is pretty complex to install frankly, so hopefully the steps above will help you out.